# String with '0' in the Beginning is not being written in the Cell

Tags: google-apps-script

```
  if (DisplayedAcessCode.length <= 4 ) {
   DisplayedAcessCode = '0'+'0'+ DisplayedAcessCode
  }
  else if (DisplayedAcessCode.length <= 5 )
   {
   DisplayedAcessCode = '0'+ DisplayedAcessCode
  }
   else if (DisplayedAcessCode.length <= 1 )
   {
   DisplayedAcessCode = '0'+'0'+'0'+'0'+'0'+ DisplayedAcessCode
  }


   aS.getRange("G31").setValue(DisplayedAcessCode);
```

Result in sheet cell : 57310
Instead of : 057310
in Logger i find the string as "057310"

I have tried converting into strings from integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by default, the cells in a Google Spreadsheet are formatted as numbers, so any leading zeroes will disappear when you are entering them via GAS. Basically even if you are dealing with a string, if the cell is formatted as a number and the string can be coerced to a number without issue, Google will do that. You can do a few things to keep the leading zeroes:

- prepend an apostrophe to your string before you `setValue` (this tells the Spreadsheet to treat the value as a string regardless of the cell formatting):

```
aS.getRange("G31").setValue('\'' + DisplayedAcessCode);
```

- set the number format as text before you `setValue`:

```
aS.getRange("G31").setNumberFormat("@").setValue(DisplayedAcessCode);
```

- set the range to `plain text` via the spreadsheet itself (by clicking
  on the `123` in the menu and selecting `Plain Text`